# "if not" with verbs

Tags: idioms

[What does "if not" mean in the given sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/what-does-if-not-mean-in-the-given-sentence)

Lots of examples are shown in the above Q&A.  But most usages of "if not" seem to involve adjectives.  My question is, can we use "if not" to mean something like

> We will at least **circumvent** the problem, even when we cannot **fix** it.

Here two verbs are put into contrast.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking.  Can you use "if not" in a sentence in the way that you're asking about?

Comment: @stangdon  "By doing XYZ, we will circumvent the problem, if not fix it." Is this correct English?

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the information needed to answer it.

Comment: @ThePhoton what sort of information do you need?  I made a question to be answered by either of yes or no.

Comment: @nodakai, What stangdon asked for. Don't just reply in comments, edit your question to include the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

"at least" and "if not",, used together, is used for talking about an outcome that may **not be totally possible** but some outcome that **comes close** in some way will probably happen.

> This will *at least* bypass the problem, *if not* fix it.
>
> The organization's efforts at least will save some refugees, if not all of them.

Comment: Thanks, so we **can** use "if not" with verbs and nouns as well, that's what you mean.  Can we use it in the S part of an SVO sentence?  Like "coal, if not gold, will be mined from this mountain."